# How can I optimize this array.each in ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, array

I'm trying to optimize this bit of code and I thought I'd throw it out here to see if anyone has any ideas. I've been testing the performance using `Benchmark.measure {...}` and wrapping the entire function.

Yes, the item has a date that is a Ruby `Date`

```
  puts Benchmark.measure {
    grouped_items
  }

  def grouped_items
    unless @grouped
      @grouped = {}
      @items.each do |item|
        key = item.date
        if @grouped.has_key?(key)
          @grouped[key] << item
        else
          @grouped[key] = [item]
        end
      end
    end
    @grouped
  end
```

Thanks for any insight you care to share.

Edit #1: My first optimization. I was aiming for a slightly more succinct function and gained a .2 seconds reduction in time to process 100_000 items.

```
  def grouped_items
    unless @grouped
      @grouped = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
      @items.map {|item| @grouped[item.date] << item }
    end
    @grouped
  end
```

Edit #2: My second iteration with more or less the same performance profile but with much less code.

```
def grouped_items
  @grouped ||= @items.group_by { |item| item.date }
end
```

Edit #3: An alternative way to do the same thing above.

```
def grouped_items
  @grouped ||= @items.group_by &:date
end
```

Comment: Nope. I'll check that out.

Comment: In future can you flag for a mod to migrate, please don't cross-post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try profiling the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you aware of `Enumerable#group_by`?

```
def grouped_items
  @items.group_by{|item| item.date}
end
```

Comment: It more or less performs the same as the first edit (see above) but with much less code.

Comment: I just came back across this and wanted to comment again how awesome this solution is. :)

Comment: Just to add, you could even use symbol-to-proc here since you are grouping by an immediate method call: `@items.group_by &:date`.

Comment: Indeed, as the OP discovered and showed in his Edit #3.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
@items.group_by { |item| item.effective_date }
```

Benchmarks for the curious:

```
Ryan v1 : 1.080000   0.000000   1.080000 (  1.077599)
Ryan v2 : 0.620000   0.000000   0.620000 (  0.622756)
group_by: 0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.576531)
```